# Creating a Trigger using MySQL with a hyphen/dash in the column name

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in an existing MySQL database. The trigger I want to create is simple

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER `prmadd02_cecsproject`.`prmadd02_room_checkNumberOfBeds` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `prmadd02_room` 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

        IF NEW.number-beds < 1 OR NEW.number-beds > 3
        THEN
            SET @s0 = 'Number of Beds must be between 1 and 3!';
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = @s0;
        END IF;

    END

    $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

However when I try to execute this code I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'number' in 'NEW'
```

Before anyone asks, no I can't change the column name.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the backticks to the column name:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `prmadd02_cecsproject`.`prmadd02_room_checkNumberOfBeds` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `prmadd02_room` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`number-beds` < 1 OR NEW.`number-beds` > 3
    THEN
        SET @s0 = 'Number of Beds must be between 1 and 3!';
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = @s0;
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER;
```

It is not a good practice to name your database columns with these characters, because when you run it the database think that you are performing an operation, so you have to ESCAPE this to use it. The backticks is how you do it.

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Hi Paul, Glad that I could help. Please consider in mark it as accepted. To do so you click on the V icon in the left side of the answer.

Comment: Done and Done. Thank you again.